# Raspberry Pi remote desktop gateway tunnel

Tags: remote-desktop

For a university project, I have to remotely work on a raspberry pi. Currently, I connect to it via `ssh` in the terminal:

*Win Home PC --ssh--> uni-gateway-domain.com --ssh--> Pi.*

Now, I want to use remote desktop to work more efficiently. I followed [this](https://cyberwehr-bw.de/remotedesktop) tutorial (german).  These are the settings I set:

[image: Session]

[image: Tunnel]

On both the gateway and the pi, `xrdp` is installed. When I try to open the session putty just timeouts. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are doing RDP to localhost:11347, then you end up at the gateway's 3389, not the RPI's. The destination of the redirection should be 10.10.10.40.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to forward xwindows if you want to use Putty for that.

Why not just use Windows RDP to connect directly to the Raspberry Pi? Is port 3389 open on the Raspberry Pi? You shouldn't need to use Putty for that transaction at all.